# Controlling the motion of points in an animation

Tags: code-review, gui-construction, engineering

I am looking for a better way to show this behavior on a pressure-composition diagram for immiscible liquids (two black dots show behavior at different x-positions, only one is present otherwise):

[image]

The piston (right) is moved with a slider and that controls the y-position of the black dot `location`. Whenever the black dot passes through the purple horizontal line or blue, orange, and magenta dots, the black dot needs to stay at that position for a while (until one of the phases is vaporized) before moving again.

The way I've accomplished this for this and similar demonstrations is inefficient and buggy. Here is what I used for this one:

**Controls**

```
Control[{{comp, 0.3, "benzene composition"}, 
  If[(step == 2 ∨ step == 10), 0.01, 0], 
  If[(step == 2 ∨ step == 10), 0.99, 1], 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  Enabled -> 
   If[step == 1 ∨ step == 11 ∨ step == 3 ∨ step == 13, 
    False, True]}],
Control[{{pistonheight, 0.1, "piston height"}, 0.1, 6.5, 0.01}],
Button["reset to initial conditions", {comp = 0.3, pistonheight = 0.1,
   location = 0, step = 0}],
Control[{{location, 0}, None}],
Control[{{step, 0}, 0, 14, None}]
```

**Code that sets the y-position of the black dot `location`**

```
height = 6.5 - pistonheight;
P1 = height + 1;
P2 = height;

stop[loc_] := P2 <= loc ∧ P1 > loc;
phase = Piecewise[{{Py2[comp], 0 <= comp <= xp}, {Py1[comp], xp < comp <= 1}}];
```

**Mess**

```
If[0 < comp < 1, {
   If[(step == 0 ∨ step == 10) ∧ P2 > P, {location = P2, 
     step = 0}],
   If[(step == 0 ∨ step == 2) ∧ stop[P], {location = P, 
     step = 10}],
   If[(step == 4 ∨ step == 10) ∧ 
     stop[P] ∧ (Abs[phase - P] <= 0.2), {location = P, 
     step = 14}],
   If[step == 14, location = P],
   If[step == 14 ∧ P1 < P, {location = P1, step = 2}],
   If[
    step == 14 ∧ 
     P2 > P ∧ (Abs[phase - P] <= 0.2), {location = P2, step = 0}],
   If[step == 10, location = P],
   If[(step == 10 ∨ step == 4) ∧ 
     phase <= P1 < P, {location = P1, step = 2}],
   If[step == 2, location = P1],
   If[step == 2 ∧ P1 < phase, {location = P1, step = 4}],
   If[step == 4, location = P1]
   }];

If[comp == 0 ∨ comp == 1, {
   If[(step == 0 ∨ step == 1 ∨ step == 3) ∧ 
     P2 > P, {location = P2, step = 0}],
   If[(step == 0 ∨ step == 11 ∨ step == 13) ∧ 
     phase < P2 <= P, {location = P2, 
     If[comp == 0, step = 1, step = 3]}],
   If[(step == 1 ∨ step == 3), location = P2],
   If[(step == 1 ∨ step == 3 ∨ step == 4) ∧ 
     stop[phase], {location = phase, 
     If[comp == 0, step = 11, step = 13]}],
   If[(step == 11 ∨ step == 13) ∧ P1 < phase, {location = P1,
      step = 4}],
   If[step == 4, location = P1]
   }];
```

The idea with this code was also to be able to define regions. There has to be a better way to accomplish this because what I currently am doing is impractical.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this:

```
point[y_] := {y - 5, 10, y + 5}
point2[y_] := {y - 5, 30, y + 5}

activePoint[pts : {_, _, _}] := Sort[pts][[2]]

Manipulate[Graphics[{
   Thick, PointSize[Large],
   Darker@Green,
   Line[{{0, 10}, {40, 10}}],
   Point[{10, activePoint[point[y]]}],
   Darker@Blue,
   Line[{{0, 30}, {40, 30}}],
   Point[{30, activePoint[point2[y]]}]
   }, PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {0, 40}}], {y, 0, 40}]
```

[image: Animation]